# Spring MVC Portlet: Accessing beans from portlet context in root context

Tags: spring, portlet

It is possible to access a portlet context bean from root application context in spring mvc portlet?

Comment: The need to do that signals that there's probably something wrong with your design. So... why do you need that ?

Comment: It is because of using direct web remoting framework. Now in my project when class is in portlet context it is not possible to generate a javascript file which is a counterpart of java file.

Comment: I think that there are 2 possible solutions: 1) move some part of the logic from controllers to root web application context 2) try to make possible generation javascript files from classes instantiated in portlet context. Do you know a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If `publishContext` property of `DispatcherPortlet`is true (default value) then you can get portlet appcontext from `javax.portlet.PortletContext` as:

`ApplicationContext otherPortletContext = portletContext.getAttribute(FrameworkPortlet.PORTLET_CONTEXT_PREFIX + otherPortletName);`

then use bean of other portlet Context as:
`portletBean = otherPortletContext.getBean(beanName, beanClass);`

Note that you can get `javax.portlet.PortletContext` object by implementing `PortletContextAware`.

Comment: PortletContextAware was just the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot reach "down" like that. Portlet/servlet beans can see beans in the root context, but not the other way around.